# HealthCheck probe interval .net Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2

Can one configure the probe time when using the HealthCheck framework in .NET 2.2.? Is there a way?
Timing it, the default refresh is 30 seconds or at least that's how often mine fires.

Answer (score 4):

You can [set the period property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-6.0#health-check-publisher) of IHealthCheckPublisher execution. The default value is 30 seconds.

```cs
services.Configure<HealthCheckPublisherOptions>(options =>
{
   options.Period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
});

services.AddSingleton<IHealthCheckPublisher, SampleHealthCheckPublisher>();

services.AddHealthChecks()
  .AddCheck<SampleHealthCheck>("Sample");
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks and related packages provided by Xabaril via the BeatPulse project.

Here's the link to the repository: https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks

This package has a variety of implementations to provide health checks for different services like:

- Sql Server
- MySql
- Oracle
- Sqlite
- RavenDB
- Postgres
- EventStore
- RabbitMQ
- Elasticsearch
- Redis
- System: Disk Storage, Private Memory, Virtual Memory
- Azure Service Bus: EventHub, Queue and Topics
- Azure Storage: Blob, Queue and Table
- Azure Key Vault
- Azure DocumentDb
- Amazon DynamoDb
- Amazon S3
- Network: Ftp, SFtp, Dns, Tcp port, Smtp, Imap
- MongoDB
- Kafka
- Identity Server
- Uri: single uri and uri groups
- Consul
- Hangfire

This package makes refresh duration for probe configurable using settings in appSettings.json file.

You can find more details on the implementation for probe check here: https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/master/doc/kubernetes-liveness.md

Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, if it resolved your issue

Comment: I am using a the Microsoft Implementation, it works fine with a custom Ui's. The question was how can I limit the HealthCheck framework in .NET 2.2,